How to wait until PictureBoxes added to a FlowLayoutPanel are all completely redrawn before proceeding?
Completing a VB.NET application to display images, I run into a painting/timing issue of some sort:
I have a Form which displays a horizontal FlowLayoutPanel, to which I dynamically add PictureBox Controls to show some images.
Everything's fine until I want to display a list of these images in a browser-based Form.
The list correctly displays the images in view, but not those which are out of the viewport, unless I scroll until the end to see the whole series of images.
I grab images from each PictureBox, convert it to base64 and add it to my html stuff.
So, I have tried a scroll to the end using:
FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Item(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1).Select()

hoping that it would work but, if this scrolls effectively to the end, it does not paint the images located at the beginning of the FLP.
I also added a FlowLayoutPanel.Refresh but no change either.
So, my question is: is there a way I make all images be "displayed" or painted so that I can then grab and add them to my report?

If you have set the Image Property to an existing Bitmap object, the reference to that image is there, no matter whether the Control is visible or not. Give a better description of your context (e.g., are you drawing images in the Paint event handler of those Controls?) -- You cannot focus a PictureBox, it's explicitly constructed to prevent that. You can override this behavior, but it's not really necessary

Please, add your code and any further details to the body of the question, not in comments. Remove the unnecessary comments after -- Since you probably left WaitOnLoad to the default false value, the Image is set to null, then LoadAsync() is called in the OnPaint() method. If you want to keep the deferred loading process as it is, you can get the Images from the files directly when you need to use those images elsewhere

In the method that creates the PictureBox Controls and sets the images to show, I replaced:
[PictureBox].ImageLocation = filepath 

with:
[PictureBox].Image = Image.FromFile(filepath)


Image.FromFile(filepath) not exactly OK. You should have: Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)), True, False). See the docs about those two Boolean parameters

Thx Jimi...Will do.
As I said, images are not part of my skillset :-)
